# wpf mvvm recursive tree

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

i have two classes

```
public class leaf
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class node
{
    public ObservableCollection<node> nodeList = new ObservableCollection<node>();
    public ObservableCollection<leaf> leafList = new ObservableCollection<leaf>();
    public ObservableCollection<node> prop_nodeList { get { return nodeList; } set { nodeList = value; } }
    public ObservableCollection<leaf> prop_leafList { get { return leafList; } set { leafList = value; } }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see its work like roads or tree. node can have information on another node and leaf.

i would like to show in user control tree formated like that

[image: i make it with using Recursiv tree]

nethead is a main node, and its have two another node (b, a). node a have two node(b,c) and 2 leaf (a1, a2). but i dont do it with mvvm. when i do it with mvvm its look like

[image: i make it with mvvm]

from C# im doing only

```
this.DataContext = mainNode; // its node which hold everething (its named netHead)
```

from xaml its

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding prop_nodeList}">
        <TreeView.Resources>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:node}" ItemsSource="{Binding prop_nodeList}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:leaf}" ItemsSource="{Binding prop_leafList}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

you see what i want to do ? i want to make double treeItem in TreeView, but it doesnt work :(
please help, its projekt for Ant Algorithm and i want to do the best gui in class room

Comment: hi, you are using hierarchicaldatatemplate wrong. take a look on msdn how to use it right. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx  btw there aint better gui than old school console hehe

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know that before. but i still dont know how to make
double item in ItemTemplate

Answer (score 2):

Have a bit modified your code: Implemented root view model NodesData just to demonstrate and create startup data.  Also added property Children to have single property for the children of node. And also slightly modified xaml to use single hierarchical data template. And seems it works.

```
  public class leaf
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class node 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<node> nodeList = new ObservableCollection<node>();
    public ObservableCollection<leaf> leafList = new ObservableCollection<leaf>();
    public ObservableCollection<node> prop_nodeList { get { return nodeList; } set { nodeList = value; } }
    public ObservableCollection<leaf> prop_leafList { get { return leafList; } set { leafList = value; } }

    public ObservableCollection<object> Children
    {
        get
        {
            var children = prop_nodeList.OfType<object>();
            return new ObservableCollection<object>(children.Concat(prop_leafList.OfType<object>()));
        }
    }

}

public class NodesData 
{
    public ObservableCollection<node> RootSource { get; set; }

    public NodesData()
    {
        var rootNode = new node() { name = ">>>Head Node<<<<" };


        var b = new node() { name = "b" };
        var c = new node() { name = "c" };
        var a = new node()
                    {
                        name = "a",
                        prop_nodeList = new ObservableCollection<node>() { b, c },
                        prop_leafList = new ObservableCollection<leaf>() { new leaf() { name = "a1" }, new leaf() { name = "a2" } }
                    };
        rootNode.prop_nodeList = new ObservableCollection<node>() { b, a };

        RootSource = new ObservableCollection<node>() { rootNode };
    }
}
```

}

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <wpfApplication1:NodesData x:Key="dataSource"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootSource}" DataContext="{StaticResource dataSource}">
        <TreeView.Resources>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication1:node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication1:leaf}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>



        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, its very helpful. and if you didnt help me with my next question i would use it. my question is "is there any way to make it with two ObservableCollection ?"

Comment: and without Inheriting

Comment: Without using hierarchical data template and treeview control - I guess  you can try, just data templates. But it is more complex,  Children can be just ObservableCollecttion<object> so if there are no very specific requirements I would suggest to proceed with suggested approach. Without inheriting yes as I said Children can be observable collection of objects. I have used inherting just not to dublicate  name in leaf and node.

Comment: i'm really dont want to Inhearing, its two seperate classes, im to pedantic to Inherting classes only for ViewModel.
now when you guys, help me i write this:
http://pastebin.com/Q3vPKFnn
 but its doesnt work, such i predict

Comment: just updated without inheriting. Do not forget about xaml changes.

Comment: everything works such as i wanted.
im greatful. Thanks :)
now i see it, its no way to make it with two seperate property. its important :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set the ItemsSource to a collection containing the root node if you want the root node shown as well.

As for the leaves not showing... you need a DataTemplate for them, not HierarchicalDataTemplate. I suspect binding errors prevent it from rendering correctly, since the leaf does not have a children collection.

Just noticed that this is sort of a homework question so I won't go on for longer. Look at the binding errors (enable WPF tracing to see them in the output window) and try to figure it out from there.